# How to display user details like name, email and image on navigation drawer on Google Sign In?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I wanted to fetch the user details like name, email id and image when a user logs in with google on the navigation drawer header. I successfully authenticated the user via Google sign in but the app crashes while setting name email and picture on the drawer.

The error shows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

And the code related to it is

```
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.USER_KEY).child(mFirebaseUser.getEmail().replace(".", ","))
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null){
                        Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                        Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                                .load(users.getPhotoUrl())
                                .into(mDisplayImageView);
                        mNameTextView.setText(users.getUser());
                        mEmailTextView.setText(users.getEmail());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Is there any way to fix this issue? Or an alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message tells you the exact problem in your code. So you are calling `replace()` method `on a null object reference`. Which means that `mFirebaseUser.getEmail()` return `null`. To solve this, you need to instantiate the `mFirebaseUser` object before actually using it, like this:

```
FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

And to get user email, just use the following line of code:

```
if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
    String userEmail = mFirebaseUser.getEmail();
}
```

Comment: Its not crashing now but I didn't got what I was trying to achieve. I wanted to display the details like name, email address and image on the navigation header but it's not showing

Comment: This code just instantiate the `mFirebaseUser` object and is getting the user email out of it. I see you need to replace the `.` with the `,`.  What else would you like to achieve?

Comment: Displaying the user name, email address and image on navigation drawer header

Comment: Once we have solved the issue regarding the error in your reference, the other part of your code should work or do you have an error?

Comment: The error is solved. But the rest of the code isn't working.

Comment: The error is solved, that's good. You say that the rest of the code isn't working. Do you have an error? What is the behaviour? If don't provide me details I cannot be much of a help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172480/discussion-between-joy-dey-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: That is basically another issue. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: If you think that my answer helped you for solving the initial issue of this post, please consider accepting it. Thanks!